# Does Firebase cloud messaging detect when a device comes back online?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Does `Firebase cloud messaging` detect when a device comes back online and sends any pending notifications that could not reach the device while it was offline (without network / turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime), you could see (emphasis mine):

> If the device is not connected to FCM, the message is stored until a connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules). **When a connection is established, FCM delivers all pending messages to the device.** If the device never gets connected again (for instance, if it was factory reset), the message eventually times out and is discarded from FCM storage. The default timeout is four weeks, unless the time_to_live flag is set.

So in a way, it does detect it.

Comment: Thanks. "When a connection is established" -- do you have knowledge of how this actually takes place? How to guarantee the re-delivery of a message if a device is offline and comes back online?

Comment: How it works is a bit broad and there's no detailed documentation on how it works. Plus, it may also vary depending on what platform your client app is.